# Docker Deskop 2.3.0.2 for Windows - Host Volumes Stopped Working

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-desktop

I have a compose (yml) file that I use to bring servers up and down as I need them.  I have just updated my Docker Desktop on Windows to version 2.3.0.2.
[image: Docker Desktop V2.3.0.2]

My Sql Server instance will not stay running now.

My yaml file is simply:

```
 version: '3.2'

services:  
  dev-mssql-server:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
    container_name: dev-mssql-server
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: C:\Data\sqlserver-linux-container
        target: /var/opt/mssql/data
    networks:
      dvlpnet:
        ipv4_address:  172.22.0.20
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=ReallyBitchin#1Password
      - MSSQL_PID=Developer
    ports:
      - "15785:1433"

networks:
  dvlpnet:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet:  172.22.0.0/24

volumes:
  sqlserver-linux-container:
```

And the message from the Docker Dashboard is:

```
Attaching to dev-mssql-server
dev-mssql-server | SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.
dev-mssql-server | This container is running as user mssql.
dev-mssql-server | Your master database file is owned by root.
dev-mssql-server | To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
dev-mssql-server | 2020-05-18 18:25:20.88 Server Setup step is FORCE copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\model_replicatedmaster.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/model_replicatedmaster.mdf'.
2020-05-18 18:25:21.13 Server ERROR: Setup FAILED copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\model_replicatedmaster.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/model_replicatedmaster.mdf': 1(Incorrect function.)
dev-mssql-server | ERROR: BootstrapSystemDataDirectories() failure (HRESULT 0x80070001)
dev-mssql-server exited with code 1
```

And some of the Docker log file is here:

```
[13:26:48.754][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] stopping accepting connections on docker-proxy-port-approver/approver-6129484611666145821 tcp forward from 0.0.0.0:15785 to 0.0.0.0:0
[13:26:48.754][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] wsl unexpose error:Post http://unix/forwards/unexpose/port: open \\\\.\\pipe\\dockerWsl2BootstrapExposePorts: The system cannot find the file specified.
[13:26:48.754][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] external: POST /forwards/unexpose/port 200 \"Go-http-client/1.1\" \"\
[13:26:49.255][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] proxy << POST /v1.25/containers/ab6315ce510c8143da6760f54425ba625a2acffb5e6fb387ca3120b992b7aef6/start (515.4339ms)\n
[13:26:49.257][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] vpnkitExposer.Add(ab6315ce510c8143da6760f54425ba625a2acffb5e6fb387ca3120b992b7aef6, [TCP 0.0.0.0:15785 -> 127.0.0.1:15785])
[13:26:49.257][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] adding docker-containers/ab6315ce510c8143da6760f54425ba625a2acffb5e6fb387ca3120b992b7aef6 tcp forward from 0.0.0.0:15785 to 127.0.0.1:15785
[13:26:49.258][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] wsl expose error:Post http://unix/forwards/expose/port: open \\\\.\\pipe\\dockerWsl2BootstrapExposePorts: The system cannot find the file specified.
[13:26:49.260][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] grpcfuseSharer.Add(ab6315ce510c8143da6760f54425ba625a2acffb5e6fb387ca3120b992b7aef6, [src=C:\\Data\\sqlserver-linux-container,dst=/var/opt/mssql/data,option=rw])
[13:26:49.260][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] lazily recomputing file watches
[13:26:49.260][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] watching path C:\\Data\\sqlserver-linux-container\\
[13:26:49.260][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] invalidating caches for C:\\Data\\sqlserver-linux-container\\
[13:26:49.261][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] proxy >> GET /containers/ab6315ce510c8143da6760f54425ba625a2acffb5e6fb387ca3120b992b7aef6/json\n
[13:26:49.266][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] proxy << GET /containers/ab6315ce510c8143da6760f54425ba625a2acffb5e6fb387ca3120b992b7aef6/json (5.0047ms)\n
[13:26:49.269][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] caches invalidated for C:\\Data\\sqlserver-linux-container\\
```

I made sure that my C drive was still shared properly in the new version of Docker Desktop.  I even redundantly added c:\data and c:\data\sqlserver-linux-container directories as shared after I started seeing these errors.

I was not able to find much out on the interwebbies on how this new version of Docker Desktop handles Windows host volumes.

I removed version 2.3.0.2 and reinstalled the older version 2.2.0.5 and everything worked happily again.

Has anyone run into this?  Is there a solution yet that I was not able to find?

Comment: What happens if you change it to this? `/host_mnt/c/Data/sqlserver-linux-container`

Comment: I did try that also.  Received the same error message.  Thanks for the suggestion though. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have same problem. Our scouting showed that:

- Docker Desktop 2.3.0.2 (changelog)

> Docker Desktop now allows sharing individual folders, rather than whole drives, giving more control to users over what is being shared.

- Microsoft suggests mapping subdirectories separately:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-docker?view=sql-server-ver15#mount-a-host-directory-as-data-volume

```
      mssql:
        container_name:  $PROJECTNAME-mssql
        restart: ${DOCKER_RESTART}
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU4-ubuntu-16.04"
        volumes:
          # konfiguracja dla lokalnej bazy mssql na dockerze
          - ./var/data/mssql/data:/var/opt/mssql/data
          - ./var/data/mssql/log:/var/opt/mssql/log
          - ./var/data/mssql/secrets:/var/opt/mssql/secrets
```

Still doesn't work.

Edit:

There is an active issue registered on github related to this one:

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/6646